# Jquery datatable Action is not working

Tags: jquery, struts2, datatables

I have datatable with custom actions for export excel , but these actions not firing the to struts action class.

```
 var oTable = $("#products").dataTable({
       "aaData": newarray,
       "bProcessing": true,
       "bDeferRender": true,
       "bFilter": false,
       "bRetrieve": true,
       "bPaginate": true,
       "bJQueryUI": true,
       "sPaginationType": "two_button",
       "sDom": '<"top"<"actions">lfpi<"clear">><"clear">rt<"bottom">',
       "bSort": true
});

 function createTableActions(){
         $("div.actions").append('<a id="excelExport" class="actionButton" alt="Export to Excel" title="Export to Excel" href="pexport"></a>');
     }
```

Please refer All the code in [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/rwPFx/29/)

**The same link working in page but not from Jquery dialog.**

```
$("div.actions").append('<a id="excelExport" class="actionButton" alt="Export to Excel" title="Export to Excel" href="pexport"></a>');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add:

```
"fnDrawCallback": function( oSettings ) {
   createListTableActions();
}
```

Comment: I'm call method from outside of datatable , getting error : SyntaxError: invalid label
"fnDrawCallback": function( oSettings ) {

Comment: You should do inside datatable and it will call your external function when datatable will be drawed. http://datatables.net/usage/callbacks otherwise I suppose probably it will not find table because it's not loaded yet.

Comment: Add this solution after "bSort": true, "fnDrawCallback": function( oSettings ) ...

Comment: Already i tried there , its giving me an error ReferenceError: createListTableActions is not defined createListTableActions(); - The method i had definded outside datatable.